# install Kony on mac os

Tags: ios, macos, sdk, temenos-quantum

I installed KONY (5.5) on Mac OS  ( 10.9.2),Also installed JDK and Xcode.

How to connect Kony with  iOSSimulator?

http://developer.kony.com/twiki/pub/Portal/Docs/Kony_Studio_InstallationGuide_Installer.pdf

Above link from KONY mentioned, it supports only Windows (windows / 7 / 8 / Vista) 
but not mac OS .

Please advice.

Comment: What do you mean by "connect"?  Don't you mean "How do I use Kony in my iOS app"?

Comment: no , when install Kony , you should connect Kony with iOS SDK and simulator to (Run IOS APP) , wothout connect SDK (cant run on ios device)

Answer (score 2):

Please try these steps:

- Configure Xcode settings and device options through preferences
  window (Kony Dev Studio -> iOS)

[image: Xcode preferences]

- Once done you can do a build. If you notice a green tick on the
  iPhone emulator, it indicates that build went fine (you can also edit
  Xcode details by doing a right click on the emulator icon)

[image: iPhone emulator]

- Double clicking on the emulator "iPhone" will extract and create XCode project from Kony build

[image: Build process: extract xcode project from Kony build]

- You can then run the application on emulator / device from Xcode

[image: Extracted Xcode project]